# how to get a total from a static method

Tags: java, variables, methods, static

Ok so I posted the first part of this already (I wasn't getting the correct output for hotdog stand sales) and got a ton of help, but now I can't figure out to return the correct total from all the different stands. I got the stands to increment by using the 'this' keyword, but I can't figure out how to then get the static getTotal to increment all the stands, correctly.

```
public class HotDogStand {

    //instance variable declaration
    private int IDNumber;
    private int hotDogsSold=0;
    private static int totalSold=0;
    //constructor
    public HotDogStand(int ID, int sold)
    {
        this.IDNumber=ID;
        this.hotDogsSold=sold;
    }
    //sets ID for all the stands
    public void setID(int ID)
    {
        this.IDNumber=ID;
    }
    public int getID()
    {
        return IDNumber;
    }
    //invoked each time a stand makes a sale
    public void justSold()
    {
            this.hotDogsSold++;
            totalSold=hotDogsSold;
    }
    //gets the totals for the different stands
    public int getSold()
    {
        return this.hotDogsSold;
    }

    // returns total sales of all stands
    public static int getTotal()
    {
        return totalSold;
    }

}
```

and my test class

```
public class HotDogTest {
public static void main(String[]args){
    HotDogStand stand1=new HotDogStand(1, 1);
    HotDogStand stand2=new HotDogStand(2, 2);
    HotDogStand stand3=new HotDogStand(3, 7);

    stand1.getID();
    stand2.getID();
    stand3.getID();
    stand1.setID(1);
    stand2.setID(2);
    stand3.setID(3);
    stand1.justSold();
    stand2.justSold();
    stand3.justSold();
    stand1.justSold();
    stand1.justSold();
    stand1.justSold();
    stand3.justSold();

    System.out.println("Stand " + stand1.getID() + " sold " + stand1.getSold());
    System.out.println("Stand " + stand2.getID() + " sold " + stand2.getSold());
    System.out.println("Stand " + stand3.getID() + " sold " + stand3.getSold()); 

    System.out.println("The total amount of hotdogs sold by all the stands was "+HotDogStand.getTotal());

}
```

}

This returns:
Stand 1 sold 5
Stand 2 sold 3
Stand 3 sold 9
The total amount of hotdogs sold by all the stands was 9

So it is invoking the justSold method correctly and incrementing correctly, but it is pulling the total from just one stand.

Answer (score 5):

Your changing totalSold each time justSold() is called, not incrementing it as you need to. i.e., change this:

```
public void justSold()
{
        this.hotDogsSold++;
        totalSold=hotDogsSold;
}
```

to this:

```
public void justSold()
{
        this.hotDogsSold++;
        totalSold++;
}
```

Comment: Just beat me too it, this is why the totalSold is set to the last stand to sell a dog.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to what you're using can be to maintain the created stands in a list and calculate totals on demand. This depends on your use case.

Here is how:

```
public class HotDogStand {

    // create static list of all stands created
    private List<HotDogStand> stands = new ArrayList<HotDogStand>();

    //  in the constructor, make sure the stand is added to the list
    public HotDogStand(...){
        HotDogStand.stands.add(this);
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    // calculate total sales of all stands using the list
    public static int getTotal()
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (HotDogStand stand : HotDogStand.stands){
            total += stand.getSold();
        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree that this could work, and I will 1+ this answer, and in fact I think that it's better than use of a static variable, but you're going to maintain a List of stands, of course you'll probably not do it within the HotDogStand class.

Comment: This can be altered in many ways depends on the use case. The stand ID can be it's index in the list if it's never deleted, you could use a list sorted by maximum sold, you can give a name and use a `Map<String, HotDogStand>` to search for existing stands. It's just nice to know as an alternative.